# Does the order of Q matter?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have found the eigenvalue  and from that I have found the eigenspaces of A. The next step is to find orthonormal eigenvectors. The problem has three different eigenspaces. When I was solving the problem I randomly picked one and let it be v1 to solve for v2 and v3. The book picked a different eigenspace, from the three, as v1. Does it matter that I didn't pick the same eigenspace as the book because it will change the order when I construct a matrix Q? We have the same values but column two and one are switched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter.

You are free to choose **any** order you like.

Just be consistent of the placement of the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors should follow those.

Comment: Indeed it is! The weekend is a'comin'!